# .net System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.sort nullable int

Tags: c#, .net

How do I sort a list on a nullable int property using `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.Sort`?

Or do I have to do a manual sort because that's not possible?

Comment: ... and what was wrong with the result?

Comment: What is the behavior you what? Do you want the null first, last?

Comment: i haven't tried anything yet because i don't know what to try. @vcsjones i want the null first.

Comment: For example, this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to decide how a null value compares with items with a value.  Then you can perform the comparison.  For example if you decide that null is always "less than" a non-null:

```
list.Sort((x,y) => {
  if(!x.Nullable.HasValue) {
     if(!y.Nullable.HasValue) return 0; // equal
     else return -1; // y is greater
  }
  else
  {
    if(!y.Nullable.HasValue) return 1; // x is greater
    if(x == y) return 0; // equal
    if(x < y) return -1; // y is greater
    else return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, if you want to consider `null` less than a non-null value, that's the default sorting implementation and can just call `list.Sort()` but good example to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Since they want null firsts, they can use the default sorting implementation:

```
List<int?> myList = new List<int?>() { 2, -3, null, 9 };

myList.Sort();

for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(myList[i]);  //null, -3, 2, 9
```

If you do need a different order, use Peter Ritchie's solution.

EDIT: Just realized, this is probably for a nullable property of a class in the list, in which case use LINQ's default `OrderBy` implementation:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int? Value;
}

List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>()
{
    new MyClass() { Value = 2},
    new MyClass() { Value = -3},
    new MyClass() { Value = null},
    new MyClass() { Value = 9},
};

var sorted = myList.OrderBy(entry => entry.Value).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(sorted[i].Value); //null, -3, 2, 9
```

Another case, if you don't want to use LINQ, is to use the default comparer with the `List.Sort` method:

```
myList.Sort((x, y) =>
    {
        return System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<int?>.Default.Compare(x.Value, y.Value);
    });
```