# OrderByDescending isn't working C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to bind a sorted list(desc) to a RadioButtonList control. But this isn't working. The list gets bound in ascending order.

**aspx:**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl" runat="server"  AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
DataTextField="OptionText" DataValueField="Value">                                        
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**c#:**

```
List<Options> lst = GetList();
rbl.DataSource = (lst.FindAll(x => x.QId == 5)).OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToList();
rbl.DataBind();

public class Option
{
    private int _QId;
    public int QId
    {
        get { return _QId; }
        set { _QId = value; }
    }

    private string _OptionText;
    public string OptionText
    {
        get { return _OptionText; }
        set { _OptionText = value; }
    }

    private int? Value;
    public int? Value
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set { _Value = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating 3 lists to get your datasource. Are you sure that this cannot be done in `GetList`? To help you we have to see the class  `Options` and some sample objects.

Comment: I'm only sure that it cannot be sorted in GetList. Because for the next Id say '6', it will be asc.

Comment: What is the type of Value (`x.Value`) ?

Comment: Change to `OrderBy`. Is it now decending? Then you've got some other reversal that inverts the sorting.

Comment: Yes it has to be sorted by `Value`. This property is of type `int`

Comment: I'd replace `FindAll` with `Where`, because what's the point of creating a filtered list just to throw it away again. For the actual bug, I'd try something that dumps the list before the databinding, to narrow down whether the order by isn't working, or the databinding is affecting things in some other way after it.

Comment: You're sorting a nullable type, I'm not too sure how LINQ handles this with ordering but you should be checking the value of the nullable not the nullable itself. So `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Value)` - I have a feeling you will need something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803310/net-system-collections-generic-listt-sort-nullable-int

Comment: What is the question? What is the actual problem? What did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: I changed the Value property to `private int Value;` . This worked

Comment: @timothyclifford This can be shorted to:  `.OrderByDescending(x => x.HasValue ? x.Value.Value : int.MinValue)`  (or `int.MaxValue` to move where the nulls are)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this has to do with you using `AppendDataBoundItems="true"`. If you really just want to append new items you could consider just adding them

```
foreach(var item in (lst.FindAll(x => x.QId == 5)).OrderByDescending(x => x.Value))
{
    lst.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(item.OptionText, item.QId));
}
```

Not a beauty, but at least you're in control. Otherwise consider creating a `DataTable` and use that as datasource.

*Note: found a related problem [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1551152.aspx?Unable%20to%20Sort%20Data%20Bound%20DropDownList%20when%20AppendDataBoundItems%20is%20true%20)*